# how to move markers in google map API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, dictionary, marker

I want to move 2 markers on the same google map but i can't find the problem in my code. I can move the 1st marker but i can't move the second one, it is possible to move two markers at the same time on the same map?
How i can move 2 markers at the same time?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML5</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=650, user-scalable=yes">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }

      #mapcanvas {
        height: 97%;
      }

      #info {
        width: auto;
        margin: 5px;
        height: 3%;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      var map;
      var latLonList = [
        { lat: 45.54169245190391, lon: -73.53928729891777 },
        { lat: 45.54173002374242, lon: -73.53945091366768 },
        { lat: 45.541743173879944, lon: -73.53949382901192 },
        { lat: 45.541790138631775, lon: -73.53962525725365 },
        { lat: 45.541844617694764, lon: -73.53980496525764 },
        { lat: 45.54189721811927, lon: -73.5399578511715 },
        { lat: 45.54193666840536, lon: -73.5401026904583 },
        { lat: 45.54198363299557, lon: -73.5402475297451 },
        { lat: 45.542068169159045, lon: -73.5405720770359 },
        { lat: 45.54214706946365, lon: -73.54082688689232 },
        { lat: 45.54222221250792, lon: -73.54105487465858 },
        { lat: 45.54226729828628, lon: -73.54119434952736 },
        { lat: 45.54235746973452, lon: -73.54123994708061 },
        { lat: 45.542543447889805, lon: -73.5411112010479 },
        { lat: 45.542718154081314, lon: -73.54099586606026 },
        { lat: 45.54289661683465, lon: -73.54089394211769 },
        { lat: 45.54298866582284, lon: -73.54103341698647 },
        { lat: 45.54308071466031, lon: -73.54133650660515 },
        { lat: 45.543180277518914, lon: -73.5413445532322 },
        { lat: 45.54330050413203, lon: -73.54127749800682 },
        { lat: 45.54337001002545, lon: -73.54111924767494 }
      ]

      $(document).ready(function () {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(43, 0),
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map($('#mapcanvas')[0], mapOptions);

        //*********************************************************************
        // Add the layer showing the inventory
        //*********************************************************************

        var marker = null;
        var markerTwo = null;
        var i = 0;
        var j = 1;

        function autoUpdate() {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

            var newPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latLonList[i].lat, latLonList[i].lon);

            var secondPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latLonList[j].lat, latLonList[j].lon);


            if (marker) {
              // Marker already created - Move it
              marker.setPosition(newPoint);
            }
            else {
              // Marker does not exist - Create it
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: newPoint,
                map: map,
                draggable: true
              });
            }

            if (markerTwo) {
              // Marker already created - Move it
              markerTwo.setPosition(secondPoint);
            }
            else {
              // Marker does not exist - Create it
              markerTwo = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: secondPoint,
                map: map,
                draggable: true
              });
            }

            map.setCenter(newPoint);
          });

          // Call the autoUpdate() function every 5 seconds
          setTimeout(autoUpdate, 3000);
          if (i == 20) {
            i = 0
          }
          else {
            i++;
          }
        }

        if (j == 19) {
          j = 0
        }
        else {
          j++;
        }
        autoUpdate();
      });//end document ready
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="info">trying to update location every 5 secs   -  new latitude longitude :  <span id="coordinates"></span></div>
    <div id="mapcanvas">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We won't be able to find the problem in your code either unless you show us.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/evqklv46kuen45k/googlemaps.html?dl=0

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you add the actual code to the question as it's easier to get to and going to be available for ever. If code is located anywhere else there's a chance it won't be available. What if someone doesn't have, or doesn't want, a DropBox account?

Comment: i did it! what do you think about my code? you can find a solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animating Multiple Markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245513/animating-multiple-markers)

Answer (score 2):

the answer:

```
 map=new google.maps.Map($('#mapcanvas')[0], mapOptions);



            //*********************************************************************
            // Add the layer showing the inventory
            //*********************************************************************

                var marker = null;
                var marker2 = null ; 
                var i = 0;
                function autoUpdate() {


                  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position, pos) {  
                        //var newPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                        var newPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latLonList[i].lat, latLonList[i].lon);

                        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latLonList[i+1].lat, latLonList[i+1].lon);

                        if (marker2) {
                          // Marker already created - Move it
                          marker2.setPosition(myLatlng);
                        }
                        else {
                                marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: myLatlng,
                                map: map,
                                title: 'Client 2'

                          });
                       }
                        if (marker) {
                          // Marker already created - Move it
                          marker.setPosition(newPoint);
                        }
                        else {
                          // Marker does not exist - Create it
                          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: newPoint,
                                map: map,
                                title: 'Client 1'

                          });
                        }



                        // Center the map on the new position
                        map.setCenter(myLatlng);
                  }); 

                  // Call the autoUpdate() function every 5 seconds
                  setTimeout(autoUpdate, 3000);
                  if (i == 19)
                        i = 0
                  else 
                        i++;
                }

                autoUpdate();


        });//end document ready
```

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: for the second marker *marker2* i code it : marker.setPosition(myLatlng); so i changed by  marker2.setPosition(myLatlng); the system confused between the two markers :P

Answer (score 2):

http://geekonjava.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-make-animated-moving-marker-on.html

Follow This link It Will Helps You

```css
html{height:100%;}
body{height:100%;margin:0px;font-family: Helvetica,Arial;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>GeekOnJava: Directions Complex</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService;
  var stepDisplay;
 
  var position;
  var marker = [];
  var polyline = [];
  var poly2 = [];
  var poly = null;
  var startLocation = [];
  var endLocation = [];
  var timerHandle = [];
    
  
  var speed = 0.000005, wait = 1;
  var infowindow = null;
  
  var myPano;   
  var panoClient;
  var nextPanoId;
  
  var startLoc = new Array();
  startLoc[0] = 'rio claro, trinidad';
  startLoc[1] = 'preysal, trinidad';
  startLoc[2] = 'san fernando, trinidad';
  startLoc[3] = 'couva, trinidad';

  var endLoc = new Array();
  endLoc[0] = 'princes town, trinidad';
  endLoc[1] = 'tabaquite, trinidad';
  endLoc[2] = 'mayaro, trinidad';
  endLoc[3] = 'arima, trinidad';


  var Colors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF"];


function initialize() {  

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    { 
      size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
    });

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    address = 'Trinidad and Tobago'
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
     map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);

    }); 
  // setRoutes();
  } 


function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
// alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: label,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
        marker.myname = label;


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    return marker;
}  

function setRoutes(){   

    var directionsDisplay = new Array();

    for (var i=0; i< startLoc.length; i++){

    var rendererOptions = {
        map: map,
        suppressMarkers : true,
        preserveViewport: true
    }
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;  

    var request = {
        origin: startLoc[i],
        destination: endLoc[i],
        travelMode: travelMode
    };  

        directionsService.route(request,makeRouteCallback(i,directionsDisplay[i]));

    }   


    function makeRouteCallback(routeNum,disp){
        if (polyline[routeNum] && (polyline[routeNum].getMap() != null)) {
         startAnimation(routeNum);
         return;
        }
        return function(response, status){
          
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var route = response.routes[0];
            startLocation[routeNum] = new Object();
            endLocation[routeNum] = new Object();


            polyline[routeNum] = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
            strokeWeight: 3
            });

            poly2[routeNum] = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
            strokeWeight: 3
            });     


            // For each route, display summary information.
            var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;


            disp = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);     
            disp.setMap(map);
            disp.setDirections(response);


            //Markers               
            for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
              if (i == 0) { 
                startLocation[routeNum].latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                startLocation[routeNum].address = legs[i].start_address;
                // marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
                marker[routeNum] = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
              }
              endLocation[routeNum].latlng = legs[i].end_location;
              endLocation[routeNum].address = legs[i].end_address;
              var steps = legs[i].steps;

              for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
                var nextSegment = steps[j].path;                
                var nextSegment = steps[j].path;

                for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
                    polyline[routeNum].getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                    //bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                }

              }
            }

         }       

         polyline[routeNum].setMap(map);
         //map.fitBounds(bounds);
         startAnimation(routeNum);  

    } // else alert("Directions request failed: "+status);

  }

}

    var lastVertex = 1;
    var stepnum=0;
    var step = 50; // 5; // metres
    var tick = 100; // milliseconds
    var eol= [];
//----------------------------------------------------------------------                
 function updatePoly(i,d) {
 // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
    if (poly2[i].getPath().getLength() > 20) {
          poly2[i]=new google.maps.Polyline([polyline[i].getPath().getAt(lastVertex-1)]);
          // map.addOverlay(poly2)
        }

    if (polyline[i].GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex+2) {
        if (poly2[i].getPath().getLength()>1) {
            poly2[i].getPath().removeAt(poly2[i].getPath().getLength()-1)
        }
            poly2[i].getPath().insertAt(poly2[i].getPath().getLength(),polyline[i].GetPointAtDistance(d));
    } else {
        poly2[i].getPath().insertAt(poly2[i].getPath().getLength(),endLocation[i].latlng);
    }
 }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function animate(index,d) {
   if (d>eol[index]) {

      marker[index].setPosition(endLocation[index].latlng);
      return;
   }
    var p = polyline[index].GetPointAtDistance(d);

    //map.panTo(p);
    marker[index].setPosition(p);
    updatePoly(index,d);
    timerHandle[index] = setTimeout("animate("+index+","+(d+step)+")", tick);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

function startAnimation(index) {
        if (timerHandle[index]) clearTimeout(timerHandle[index]);
        eol[index]=polyline[index].Distance();
        map.setCenter(polyline[index].getPath().getAt(0));

        poly2[index] = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [polyline[index].getPath().getAt(0)], strokeColor:"#FFFF00", strokeWeight:3});

        timerHandle[index] = setTimeout("animate("+index+",50)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
</script>
</head>
  
<body onload="initialize()">

<div id="tools">

    <button onclick="setRoutes();">Start</button>

</div>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_uacct = "UA-162157-1";
urchinTracker();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>GeekOnJava: Directions Complex</title>


<style>
html
{
   height:100%;
}
body
{
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  font-family: Helvetica,Arial;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please add some snippets from this link instead of posting it.

Comment: i tested it and its work for me ! and sorry about that posting link only i don't know cause i am just new in stack overflow So Sorry About Wont do that Next

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var geocoder;
    var marker;
    var people = new Array();
    var people2 = new Array();
    var latlng;
    var infowindow;
    var lats=6.9271;
     var markersz = new google.maps.Marker;
     var markers2 =  new google.maps.Marker;


    $(document).ready(function() {

        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(7.8731, 80.7718),   // Coimbatore = (11.0168445, 76.9558321)
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);


        ViewCustInGoogleMap();
    });

    window.setInterval(function(){
       ViewCustInGoogleMap();
      }, 5000);

    function ViewCustInGoogleMap() {
        //deleting the previous set mark on the map
        markersz.setMap(null);
       markers2.setMap(null);

     lats = lats+0.01;

        // Get data from database. It should be like below format or you can alter it.

        var data = '[{ "DisplayText": "DULA TEST<br/><h1>HHH</h1><a href=https://www.google.lk?st=kk target=_blank>CLICK</a>", "ADDRESS": "Coimbatore-641042", "LatitudeLongitude": "'+lats+',79.8612", "MarkerId": "Customer"}]';
        people = JSON.parse(data); 
        for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
           markersz =  setMarker(people[i]);
        }
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       //getting lats and longs from the controller
         $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost/GPS/Login/latsAndLongs',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            people2 = JSON.parse(response); 
            for (var i = 0; i < people2.length; i++) {
                //setting the current mark and returning the mark object so that it can be deleted in the next iteration
                markers2=setMarker2(people2[i]);
            }
        }
       });
        //var data2 = '[{ "DisplayText": "DULA TEST2", "ADDRESS": "Coimbatore-641042", "LatitudeLongitude": "6.5854,79.9607", "MarkerId": "Seller"}]';
        }
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    function setMarker(people) { 
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        if ((people["LatitudeLongitude"] == null) || (people["LatitudeLongitude"] == 'null') || (people["LatitudeLongitude"] == '')) {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': people["Address"] }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        draggable: false,
                        html: people["DisplayText"],
                        icon: "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-places/512/pin_1-128.png"
                    });
                    //marker.setPosition(latlng);
                    //map.setCenter(latlng);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
                        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    //alert(people["DisplayText"] + " -- " + people["Address"] + ". This address couldn't be found");
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker;
            var latlngStr = people["LatitudeLongitude"].split(",");
            var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
            var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                draggable: false,               // cant drag it
                html: people["DisplayText"],    // Content display on marker click
                icon: "http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-a5485b563efc4511e0cd8bd04ad0fe9e.png"       // Give ur own image
            });

            //marker.setMap(null);
            //marker.setPosition(latlng);
            //map.setCenter(latlng);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
            return marker;
        }
    }
   //----------------------------- 
   function setMarker2(people) {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        if ((people["LatitudeLongitude"] == null) || (people["LatitudeLongitude"] == 'null') || (people["LatitudeLongitude"] == '')) {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': people["Address"] }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        draggable: false,
                        html: people["DisplayText"],
                        icon: "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-places/512/pin_1-128.png"
                    });
                    //marker.setPosition(latlng);
                    //map.setCenter(latlng);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
                        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert(people["DisplayText"] + " -- " + people["Address"] + ". This address couldn't be found");
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            var latlngStr = people["LatitudeLongitude"].split(",");
            var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
            var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                draggable: false,               // cant drag it
                html: people["DisplayText"],    // Content display on marker click
                icon: "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsimple-places/512/pin_1-128.png"       // Give ur own image
            });
            //marker.setPosition(latlng);
            //map.setCenter(latlng);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
        return marker;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Move a list of marker and zoom particular marker while iterating. 
1. Get Imei_no. 
2. Push imei_no in variable.
3. Create Map.
4. Get details based on imei_no.
5. Create Maker.
6. Push maker in test.
7. Delete marker.
8. Return to autoUpdate.

Live Tracking Done by Sureshchan...

```
     if (true) {              

            var listimei = [];
            $scope.listimei = [];

            $http.get('school/transport/scroute/viewIMEI?imeiNo=' + routeid).success(function(response) {
                //1.
                console.log(response);
                if (response.viewRoute == 0) {
                    logger.logError("IMEI No. not available");
                    $state.go("app.school.scTransport.scVehicleTracking.list");

                } else {

                    //brown
                    $scope.brown = response.viewRoute[0].emptveh;

                    //2.
                    for (var b = 0; b < response.viewRoute.length; b++) {
                        listimei.push(response.viewRoute[b].imeiNo);                        
                    }


                        //3.
                        var mapOptions = {
                                center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.0037, 80.1476),
                                zoom: 17,
                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                              };

                              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('viewallmap'), mapOptions);

                              var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                           var test = [];
                           var marker;


                        function autoUpdate() {                             

                           if (marker == null){

                                $scope.locData = [];
                                var y = 0;
                                var g = 0;
                                var r = 0;
                                var n = 0;



                                    $http.get('school/transport/scroute/getListImei?imeiNo=' + listimei).success(function(response) {
                                        //4.
                                        console.log(response);
                                        $scope.assetloader = true;
                                        for(var l = 0;l<response.viewImeiList.length;l++){                                           

                                            //time
                                            var startTime = new Date();
                                            var endTime = new Date(response.viewImeiList[l].lastmove);
                                            var difference = startTime.getTime() - endTime.getTime();
                                            var resultInMinutes = difference / 60000;
                                            var result = Math.round(resultInMinutes);

                                            //for date                           
                                            var dateObj = new Date(response.viewImeiList[l].lastmove);
                                            var month1 = ("0" + (dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);//months from 1-12
                                            var day1 =  ("0" + dateObj.getUTCDate()).slice(-2); 
                                            var year1 = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
                                            var  testdate = year1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + day1;                                        
                                            var now = new Date();
                                            var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
                                            var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                                            var today = now.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);

                                            if (response.viewImeiList[l].nosignal == 1) {
                                                $scope.black = n + 1;
                                                n++;
                                            }else if(testdate != today){
                                                $scope.black = n + 1;
                                                n++;
                                                var title = '<b>Vehicle No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].vehname + '<br> <b>IMEI No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].imeiNo + '<br> <b>Reg No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].regno + '<br> <b> Speed : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].speed + ' KMPH <br> <b> Over Speed Limit : </b> 50 KMPH <br> <b> Last Movement Detected Time : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].lastmove + '<br>';
                                                $scope.view = [];
                                                $scope.view.push(response.viewImeiList[l].vehname, title,response.viewImeiList[l].latitude, response.viewImeiList[l].longitude, "000000","FFFFFF");
                                                $scope.locData.push($scope.view);
                                            }                                             
                                            else if (response.viewImeiList[l].speed == 0) {
                                                $scope.yellow = y + 1;
                                                y++;
                                                var title = '<b>Vehicle No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].vehname + '<br> <b>IMEI No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].imeiNo + '<br> <b>Reg No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].regno + '<br> <b> Speed : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].speed + ' KMPH <br> <b> Over Speed Limit : </b> 50 KMPH <br> <b> Last Movement Detected Time : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].lastmove + '<br>';
                                                $scope.view = [];
                                                $scope.view.push(response.viewImeiList[l].vehname, title,response.viewImeiList[l].latitude, response.viewImeiList[l].longitude, "e5ff00","000000");
                                                $scope.locData.push($scope.view);
                                            } else if (response.viewImeiList[l].speed != 0 && result > 15) {
                                                $scope.yellow = y + 1;
                                                y++;
                                                var title = '<b>Vehicle No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].vehname + '<br> <b>IMEI No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].imeiNo + '<br> <b>Reg No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].regno + '<br> <b> Speed : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].speed + ' KMPH <br> <b> Over Speed Limit : </b> 50 KMPH <br> <b> Last Movement Detected Time : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].lastmove + '<br>';
                                                $scope.view = [];
                                                $scope.view.push(response.viewImeiList[l].vehname, title, response.viewImeiList[l].latitude, response.viewImeiList[l].longitude, "e5ff00","000000");
                                                $scope.locData.push($scope.view);
                                            } else if (response.viewImeiList[l].speed > 50 && result < 15) {
                                                $scope.red = r + 1;
                                                r++;
                                                var title = '<b>Vehicle No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].vehname + '<br> <b>IMEI No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].imeiNo + '<br> <b>Reg No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].regno + '<br> <b> Speed : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].speed + ' KMPH <br> <b> Over Speed Limit : </b> 50 KMPH <br> <b> Last Movement Detected Time : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].lastmove + '<br>';
                                                $scope.view = [];
                                                $scope.view.push(response.viewImeiList[l].vehname, title, response.viewImeiList[l].latitude, response.viewImeiList[l].longitude, "FF0000","000000");
                                                $scope.locData.push($scope.view);
                                            } else {
                                                $scope.green = g + 1;
                                                g++;
                                                var title = '<b>Vehicle No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].vehname + '<br> <b>IMEI No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].imeiNo + '<br> <b>Reg No : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].regno + '<br> <b> Speed : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].speed + ' KMPH <br> <b> Over Speed Limit : </b> 50 KMPH <br> <b> Last Movement Detected Time : </b> ' + response.viewImeiList[l].lastmove + '<br>';
                                                $scope.view = [];
                                                $scope.view.push(response.viewImeiList[l].vehname, title, response.viewImeiList[l].latitude, response.viewImeiList[l].longitude, "00ff00","000000");
                                                $scope.locData.push($scope.view);
                                            }

                                        }

                                             var locations = $scope.locData;

                                            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                                                    var city = locations[i][0];
                                                    var state = locations[i][1];
                                                    var lat = locations[i][2];
                                                    var lng = locations[i][3];
                                                    var desc = locations[i][4];
                                                    var textcol = locations[i][5];
                                                    var z = i;
                                                    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                                                    var content = '<div class="map-content"><h3>' + state +
                                                         '</h3></div>';

                                                    //5.

                                                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                        map: map,
                                                        title: state,
                                                        position: myLatLng,
                                                        icon : 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=' + city + '|' + desc + '|' +textcol,
                                                        draggable : true,
                                                        zIndex: z
                                                    });

                                                    //6.
                                                    test.push(marker);

                                                    //mouseover
                                                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content) {
                                                        return function() {
                                                            infoWindow.setContent(content);
                                                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                                                        }
                                                    })(marker, content));

                                                    // add the double-click event listener
                                                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function(event){
                                                        map = marker.getMap();

                                                        map.setCenter(overlay.getPosition()); // set map center to marker position
                                                        smoothZoom(map, 12, map.getZoom()); // call smoothZoom, parameters map, final zoomLevel, and starting zoom level
                                                    })


                                                    // the smooth zoom function
                                                    function smoothZoom (map, max, cnt) {
                                                        if (cnt >= max) {
                                                                return;
                                                            }
                                                        else {
                                                            y = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(event){
                                                                google.maps.event.removeListener(y);
                                                                self.smoothZoom(map, max, cnt + 1);
                                                            });
                                                            setTimeout(function(){map.setZoom(cnt)}, 80);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    });               
                                    myVar = setTimeout(autoUpdate, 40000);
                            }

                            if(test.length !=0){
                                //7.
                                for (var k = 0; k < test.length; k++) {
                                    if (test[k].getMap() != null) {
                                        test[k].setMap(null);
                                    }                                           

                                  }

                                test1();

                            }

                        }    

                        function test1(){
                           //8.
                            test = [];
                            marker = null;
                            autoUpdate();

                        }


                        autoUpdate();                    



                }

            });

        }
```