# how to control symbols on many polylines using Play, Pause,Reset Functionality ( used Google Map API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have drawn many polylines here. I have implemented a play,pause,reset function for controlling the symbol on polyline. This works well when there is only one line.

However, I want to implement many polylines and control the animation on them via the same button.
I'm having a problem here. I'm not able to control the animation on all of them but one line.

With the help of geocodezip (Lawrence Ross, I guess), I was able to implement the slider.

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpXVZ.png)

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pranavj1001/opysL0sx/9/)

```
      // This example adds an animated symbol to a polyline.

  function initMap() {

            var line;
    var line1;
    var intervalForAnimation;
    var count = 0;
    var n = 2;
    var lineArray;
    var lineArray1;
    var allPath = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
      new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892),
      new google.maps.LatLng(12.97918167,   77.6449),
    ];
    var Colors = [
    "#FF0000", 
    "#00FF00", 
    "#0000FF", 
    "#FFFFFF", 
    "#000000", 
    "#FFFF00", 
    "#00FFFF", 
    "#FF00FF"
    ];


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 19.0760, lng: 72.8777},
      zoom: 5,
      styles: [
        {
          featureType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { saturation: -80 }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: 'road.arterial',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [
            { hue: '#00ffee' },
            { saturation: 50 }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: 'poi.business',
          elementType: 'labels',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    });

    // Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
    // supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
      var symbolSource = {
      path: 'M -2,-2 2,2 M 2,-2 -2,2',
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeWeight: 4
    };

    var symbolShape = {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
      strokeColor: '#0000FF',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0
    };

    var symbolDestination = {
      path: 'M -2,-2 2,2 M 2,-2 -2,2',
      strokeColor: '#292',
      strokeWeight: 4
    };

    // Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.

    //I used this earlier and it worked good. 

    /*line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [{lat: -33.918861, lng: 18.423300}, {lat: -35.842160, lng: 18.863525}, {lat: -39.170387, lng: 35.189209}, {lat: -26.331494, lng: 54.228516}, {lat: 0.462885, lng: 61.083984}, {lat: 19.075984, lng: 72.877656}],
      icons: [
        {
          icon: symbolShape,
          offset: '0%'
        }
      ],
      strokeColor: '#0000FF ',
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      map: map
    });*/

    //Our Secondary polyline for reseting purpose. I used this earlier and it worked good. 
    /*var line1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [{lat: -33.918861, lng: 18.423300}, {lat: -35.842160, lng: 18.863525}, {lat: -39.170387, lng: 35.189209}, {lat: -26.331494, lng: 54.228516}, {lat: 0.462885, lng: 61.083984}, {lat: 19.075984, lng: 72.877656}],
      icons: [
        {
          icon: symbolSource,
          offset: '0%'
        }, {
          icon: symbolDestination,
          offset: '100%'
        }
      ],
      strokeColor: '#0000FF ',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      map: map
    });*/

     //I tried to implement this code to create many polylines and add them to an array.
     //So that later on I can control the animation on them at once using my Play,Pause and Reset.
      for (var i = 0; i < allPath.length-1; i++) {
          var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: [allPath[i], allPath[i+1]],
          icons: [
            {
              icon: symbolShape,
              offset: '0%'
            }
          ],
          strokeColor: Colors[i],
          strokeOpacity: 0.0,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          map: map
        });
         lineArray[i] = line;
        }

            //This is my Secondary polyline which is used for reseting purpose. 
    for (var i = 0; i <allPath.length-1; i++) {
        line1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: [allPath[i], allPath[i+1]],
          icons: [
            {
              icon: symbolSource,
              offset: '0%'
            }, {
              icon: symbolDestination,
              offset: '100%'
            }
          ],
          strokeColor: Colors[i],
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          map: map
        });
        lineArray1[i] = line1;
      }

        console.log(lineArray.length);
        console.log(lineArray1.length);

      //Map boundaries
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0; i < line.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
          bounds.extend(line.getPath().getAt(i));
        }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);


    function playing() {
        for(var i=0;i<allPath.length;i++){
          intervalForAnimation = window.setInterval(function() {
              $("#map").after(animateCircle(lineArray,lineArray1,count,i));
              count = (count+0.2) % 200;
          }, 20);
        }
      }

      //Play Function
      $(".play").click(function() {
          playing();
      });

                //Pause Function
      $(".pause").click(function() {
          clearInterval(intervalForAnimation);
      });

      //Reset Function
      $(".reset").click(function(){
          count = 0;
          for(var i=0;i<allPath.length;i++){
              line1 =  lineArray1[i];
              line1.setMap(map);
          }
      });


  // Use the DOM setInterval() function to change the offset of the symbol
  // at fixed intervals.
  function animateCircle(lineArray,lineArray1,count,i) {
      line = lineArray[i];
      line1 = lineArray1[i];
      var icons = line.get('icons');
      icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
      line.set('icons', icons);
      //The Slider Function call
      $("#slider").slider("value", count);
      if (count >= 199){ 
        clearInterval(intervalForAnimation);
        line1.setMap(null);
      };
  }
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Looking at your code, I think the easiest solution is to put var lineArray and var lineArray1 outside of function InitMap (make it global variables, declare them on top of the code).  (setTimeout and )setInterval is a problem for the scope.

Comment: See [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_multipleMarkerAnimation.html), from the similar question: [Animating Multiple Markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245513/animating-multiple-markers)

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay The error is still there.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks I'm looking at that link right now. I would have to change a lot of things for that i guess.

Comment: I tried changing my code. I declared the lineArray  as 'var lineArray = [];'and similarly its counterpart lineArray1 so now the error which says 'lineArray is not defined' has gone but a new error came 'line is undefined' and 'line.get is undefined'.

Comment: I'm pleased to say that I solved the error. The problem was in the loops i had set. The code is working flawlessly now. Now I have to just make the slider go with all the lines. Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final answer to my Question.I'm posting the js function here. Advice that I learned from this Question (I'm a beginner tho)  :Just pay attention to the for loops. Set them at the right time ;)

```
  var line;
  var line1;
  var lineArray = [];
  var lineArray1 = [];
  // This example adds an animated symbol to a polyline.

  function initMap() {

    var intervalForAnimation;
    var count = 0;
    var n = 2;
    var DrivePath = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
      new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892),
      new google.maps.LatLng(12.97918167,   77.6449),
    ];
    var Colors = [
    "#FF0000", 
    "#00FF00", 
    "#0000FF", 
    "#FFFFFF", 
    "#000000", 
    "#FFFF00", 
    "#00FFFF", 
    "#FF00FF"
    ];


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 19.0760, lng: 72.8777},
      zoom: 5,
      styles: [
        {
          featureType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { saturation: -80 }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: 'road.arterial',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [
            { hue: '#00ffee' },
            { saturation: 50 }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: 'poi.business',
          elementType: 'labels',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    });

    // Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
    // supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
      var symbolSource = {
      path: 'M -2,-2 2,2 M 2,-2 -2,2',
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeWeight: 4
    };

    var symbolShape = {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
      strokeColor: '#0000FF',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0
    };

    var symbolDestination = {
      path: 'M -2,-2 2,2 M 2,-2 -2,2',
      strokeColor: '#292',
      strokeWeight: 4
    };

    // Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
    /*line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [{lat: -33.918861, lng: 18.423300}, {lat: -35.842160, lng: 18.863525}, {lat: -39.170387, lng: 35.189209}, {lat: -26.331494, lng: 54.228516}, {lat: 0.462885, lng: 61.083984}, {lat: 19.075984, lng: 72.877656}],
      icons: [
        {
          icon: symbolShape,
          offset: '0%'
        }
      ],
      strokeColor: '#0000FF ',
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      map: map
    });*/

    //Our Secondary polyline for reseting purpose
    /*var line1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [{lat: -33.918861, lng: 18.423300}, {lat: -35.842160, lng: 18.863525}, {lat: -39.170387, lng: 35.189209}, {lat: -26.331494, lng: 54.228516}, {lat: 0.462885, lng: 61.083984}, {lat: 19.075984, lng: 72.877656}],
      icons: [
        {
          icon: symbolSource,
          offset: '0%'
        }, {
          icon: symbolDestination,
          offset: '100%'
        }
      ],
      strokeColor: '#0000FF ',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      map: map
    });*/

      for (var i = 0; i < DrivePath.length-1; i++) {
          var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: [DrivePath[i], DrivePath[i+1]],
          icons: [
            {
              icon: symbolShape,
              offset: '0%'
            }
          ],
          strokeColor: Colors[i],
          strokeOpacity: 0.0,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          map: map
        });
         lineArray[i] = line;
        }

    for (var i = 0; i < DrivePath.length-1; i++) {
        line1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: [DrivePath[i], DrivePath[i+1]],
          icons: [
            {
              icon: symbolSource,
              offset: '0%'
            }, {
              icon: symbolDestination,
              offset: '100%'
            }
          ],
          strokeColor: Colors[i],
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          map: map
        });
        lineArray1[i] = line1;
      }

        console.log(lineArray.length);
        console.log(lineArray1.length);

      //Map boundaries
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0; i < line.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
          bounds.extend(line.getPath().getAt(i));
        }
      map.fitBounds(bounds);


    function playing() {
          intervalForAnimation = window.setInterval(function() {
              $("#map").after(animateCircle(count));
              count = (count+0.2) % 200;
          }, 20);
      }

      $(".play").click(function() {
          playing();
      });


      $(".pause").click(function() {
          clearInterval(intervalForAnimation);

      });

      $(".reset").click(function(){
          count = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < lineArray1.length; i++){
          line11 = lineArray1[i];
          line11.setMap(map);
        }
      });


  // Use the DOM setInterval() function to change the offset of the symbol
  // at fixed intervals.
  function animateCircle(count) {
    for(var i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++){
      line10 = lineArray[i];
      var icons = line10.get('icons');
      icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
      line10.set('icons', icons);
      $("#slider").slider("value", count);
      }
      if (count >= 199){ 
        clearInterval(intervalForAnimation);
        clearTheLines();
      };    
  }

    function clearTheLines(){
        for(var i = 0; i < lineArray1.length; i++){
          line11 = lineArray1[i];
          line11.setMap(null);
        }
    }

}
```

The Slider Function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
      max: 200,
      min: 0,
      change: function(event, ui) {
      for(var i = 0;i < lineArray.length; i++){
      console.log("ui.value=" + ui.value);
      line111 = lineArray[i];
      var icons = line111.get('icons');
      icons[0].offset = (ui.value / 2) + '%';
      line111.set('icons', icons);
      }
      }
      });
    });
```