# Google Map Move Multiple Markers Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to track live users location on google map but facing some problems, I am able to set markers on Google Map but when i am trying to loop over all markers so that to move them It is only moving the last declared Marker. Might be the problem with setTimeOut I had tried much but unable to figure out the problem.

My Markers Array that is looping over all markers and calling a desired function for movement.

```
<?php
        for($markerI=0; $markerI<$currActive; $markerI++)
        {
            ?>
        markerToMove = markers[<?php echo $markerI; ?>];
        positionOfMarker[0] = <?php echo $currLat[$markerI]; ?>;
        positionOfMarker[1] = <?php echo $currLng[$markerI]; ?>;
        var result = [32.651158, 74.070952];
        doSetTimeout(result);
        <?php
        }
        ?>

var numDeltas = 100;
    var delay = 100; //milliseconds
    var i = 0;
    var deltaLat;
    var deltaLng;

    function doSetTimeout(result) {
        setTimeout(function() { transition(result) }, delay);
    }

    function transition(result){
        i = 0;
        deltaLat = (result[0] - positionOfMarker[0])/numDeltas;
        deltaLng = (result[1] - positionOfMarker[1])/numDeltas;
        moveMarker();
    }

    function moveMarker(){
        positionOfMarker[0] += deltaLat;
        positionOfMarker[1] += deltaLng;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(positionOfMarker[0], positionOfMarker[1]);
        markerToMove.setTitle("Latitude:"+positionOfMarker[0]+" | Longitude:"+positionOfMarker[1]);
        markerToMove.setPosition(latlng);
        if(i!=numDeltas){
            i++;
            setTimeout(moveMarker, delay);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Related question: [Animating Multiple Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245513/animating-multiple-markers)

Comment: This is much different to my need.
I want just a simple thing.
Just to move multiple marker from start latitude and longitude towards the given end latitude and longitude, Thats all i need.