# Is there any way that can shows routing animation on google map?

Tags: google-maps, animation, routes, or-tools

I follow the gmaps demo of ortools and get the routing solution by the codes here:
https://woolpert.com/managing-simple-vrp-with-google-maps-platform/
I want to build a demo as 3 vehicles moving through their assigned routes.
In other words, I have the start point, must pass points and end points for each route. I want to generate a car moving animation in this route.
Is any example or API for this?

Comment: related question: [Animating Multiple Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245513/animating-multiple-markers)

Comment: It looks good, but I am not familiar with web and I use python mainly. I am wondering if there any simper google API that I can call directly?

Comment: Not that I know of